# PostgreSQL SSL Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ember.js, unicorn, heroku-postgres

We've got a WebApp mixing Ember.js, Rails, unicorn and PostgreSQL, all of them on Heroku.

All is working well, except we sometimes get a PGError

> PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() SSL error: BN lib

Most of the time, we can continue to use the app without any problems, but sometimes this error brokes the JS and we have to reload the page to be able to use the WebApp.

We believe it could be somethings like Unicorn lost the PG connection, but there is nearly [nothing on the web related to this error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=PG%3A%3AConnectionBad%3A+PQconsumeInput%28%29+SSL+error%3A+BN+lib&oq=PG%3A%3AConnectionBad%3A+PQconsumeInput%28%29+SSL+error%3A+BN+lib&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58j69i61.485j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8).

Any idea would be appreciated.

```
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:779
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:779
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:139
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:425
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:420
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:137
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:885
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:24
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:61
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:76
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:61
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/querying.rb:36
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:585
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:471
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:220
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:415
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:358
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:45
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:920
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:12
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/active_model_serializers-0.8.1/lib/active_model/array_serializer.rb:79
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/active_model_serializers-0.8.1/lib/active_model/array_serializer.rb:73
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/active_model_serializers-0.8.1/lib/active_model/array_serializer.rb:49
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:50
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:81
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:49
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:34
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/to_json.rb:16
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/active_model_serializers-0.8.1/lib/active_model/array_serializer.rb:63
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:90
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/active_model_serializers-0.8.1/lib/action_controller/serialization.rb:46
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:33
[PROJECT_ROOT]/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/set.rb:232
[PROJECT_ROOT]/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/set.rb:232
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:30
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12
[PROJECT_ROOT]/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/wicked_pdf-0.9.6/lib/pdf_helper.rb:23
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:255
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:203
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:182
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:176
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:154
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:147
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:330
app/controllers/api/v1/protocols_controller.rb:8
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:44
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.6.147/lib/new_relic/rack/error_collector.rb:43
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.6.147/lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:22
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.6.147/lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:16
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:35
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/etag.rb:23
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/head.rb:11
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:552
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:632
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.6.147/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/unicorn_instrumentation.rb:22
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.6.147/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/unicorn_instrumentation.rb:22
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:500
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:142
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/bin/unicorn:126
[PROJECT_ROOT]/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23
[PROJECT_ROOT]/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23
```

Comment: did you open a heroku support ticket yet? they respond pretty fast most of the times.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure it is related to Heroku. So we could try to contact them and/or deploy on AWS too. I was hoping someone got the same issue and fixed it previously.